# Get latest and run a bat file using TFS Continuous Integration

Tags: .net, tfs, continuous-integration

I have a .bat file in TFS which when run deploys the database changes. This files gets edited by developer daily.

I want to automate this process using TFS CI so that it does following:

- Get the latest of bat file from source control
- Run or execute the file daily
- If batch file has error than email to the team

How should I go about doing this?

Comment: Do you know what CI means? It doesn't mean "run daily", it means "run on every checkin".

Comment: Also, what part of this did you have trouble with when you tried to get it done?

Comment: Hi John, I should edit the question. Microsoft TFS CI has option to run on Check-in or daily as scheduled. I want to run script .bat file without need to add visual studio proejct or solution in the build template

Comment: No, "CI" is on checkin, period. You can schedule a nightly build, but that's not "Continuous Integration". Maybe you're confused between TFS Automated Builds, and TFS Continuous Integration builds, which are a kind of TFS Automated Build.

Comment: Also, deploying software as part of a *build* process is a bit of an anti-pattern these days. The build process should be concerned with **just** building binaries. Release is a totally separate concern, with separate tools specifically designed for the purpose. Shoehorning release actions into the build process is a recipe for disaster.

Answer (score 1):

You should use a combination of a nightly scheduled build and a release in Release Management for Visual Studio.

TF Build is not really designed for deployments but for compilation and running unit tests. RM however is designed for this purpose and can be triggered on the sucessful completion of your build.

http://nakedalm.com/create-release-management-pipeline-professional-developers/

In my example I am using PowerShell to simply copy files, but you can call your .bat (or better yet rewrite as PowerShell) to do your database update.